# TikZ using relative coordinates to position fill rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

this is my first time I am using tikz so the question is rather simple.
I am trying to achieve a simple effect of highlighting an element on my image, with tikz.

I used this threads:
[highlighting some areas in a picture by making the rest of the picture transparent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36581/highlighting-some-areas-in-a-picture-by-making-the-rest-of-the-picture-transpare)
[Highlighting part of an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78378/highlighting-part-of-an-image)

And with their help I have managed to have a code like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[totalheight=0.580\textheight, angle=90]{img/sioux-out/network1}};

\draw[red,ultra thick] (8,9.5) rectangle (10,11.5);
\fill [draw=none, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8] 
    (0,0) rectangle (8,11.5)
    (8,0) rectangle (10,9.5)
    (10,0) rectangle (16,11.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It is working quite fine, but I would really like to change some of the coordinates to the relative ones, like:

```
\fill [draw=none, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8] 
    (image.bottom left) rectangle (8,image.top)
    (8,image.bottom) rectangle (10,9.5)
    (10,image.bottom) rectangle (image.top right);
```

I tried with north, south, east west but it does not work as expected.
What I expect it to be is something like this:

[image: Example effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are predefined anchor names for the node `image`, therefore you can use:

- `(image.south west)` instead of `(image.bottom left)`
- `(image.north east)` instead of `(image.top right)`

Also coordinates can be specified as intersections of perpendicular lines:

- `(8, 0 |- image.north)` instead of `(8, image.top)`
- `(8, 0 |- image.south)` instead of `(8, image.bottom)`
- `(10, 0 |- image.south)`instead of `(10, image.bottom)`

Comment: intersections thats what i needed! Thanks a lot :)